# Aplicar evento a DatetimePicker al pulsar sobre una fecha

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datetime

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo uso del plugin DatetimePicker y estoy intentando aplicar un evento al momento en el que se pulsa una fecha, por ejemplo, que al seleccionar una fecha automáticamente se genere un alert. He tratado con el evento onclick pero no logro que funcione. Adjunto mi código:

```
<div class="row" id="datosCita">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Rellene los siguientes datos
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row"> 
            <div  id="datos">
              <select class="select2" id="listEspec">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione una especialidad --</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div id="profesionales">
              <select class="select2" id="listProf">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione un profesional --</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text"/>
            </div>
          </div>     

        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar cita</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
   <script src='js_propio/cookies.js'></script>

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: "today",
    language: 'es'
    })
  })
</script>
</body>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: HTML?, estas usando bootstrap?

Comment: estas usando un javascript?

Comment: Si, estoy usando ambas cosas. Mas abajo en el código se ven las llamadas a diversas librerías jquery y bootstrap.

Comment: bueno, el onclick no te funcionara nunca ya que tu quieres que cuando seleccione la fecha se genere un alert, pero es no funcionara con onclick ya que no es un boton

Comment: es un input por lo que veo

Comment: https://www.emenia.es/calendario-formulario-jquery/ esa pagina puede ayudarte

Comment: realiza un calendario

Comment: @CriticalGhost el enlace que le mandas es de datepicker de jquery-ui, el OP esta usando el datepicker de bootstrap

Comment: hostia verdad xD @JuankGlezz

Comment: pero el esta usando jquery no?, la etiqueta dice jquery

Comment: aaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhh si cierto no me di cuenta XD

Comment: @CriticalGhost son cosa distinta, jquery y jquery-ui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debido a que `datepicker` no tiene agregado el `click` en sus eventos no funciona, lo que si te debe funcionar es el evento `changeDate`

```
date_input.datepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  container: container,
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: "today",
  language: 'es'
}).on('changeDate',function(e){
  //mandar una alerta al cambiar fecha
})
```

Otros eventos que puedes usar los encuentras en la [documentación](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, a funcionado a la perfeccion :)